# Send text to serversocket after connecting to it

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, message, outputstream

I have a problem that I can't send text to ChatServer. My code:

```
...
try { 
        socket.connect(address);

        System.out.println("Successfully connected to server!");

        Thread fromServerToConsole = new TelnetThread(socket.getInputStream(), System.out);
        Thread fromConsoleToServer = new TelnetThread(System.in, socket.getOutputStream());

        fromConsoleToServer.setDaemon(true);

        fromServerToConsole.start();
        fromConsoleToServer.start();

        fromServerToConsole.join(); 

        socket.close();
} catch() ...
```

Where in this try block should I put something like `socket.getOutputStream().write("mystring".bytes())` if I want to send this text "mystring" to the SocketServer after connecting to it?

I tried to put this everywhere and it always didn't work, to send "mystring" I always had to press Enter in console of this client (console is for sending messages from console to the server). And the "mystring" was also printed to client's console, but it has to be printed only on the server's side.

I need to send "mystring" not from console, but automatically after connecting socket to the server.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need to send a line terminator as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to flush() the stream after writing, it may help.

As far as i know, telnet sends every singly received bytes back as an echo, so if you don't want to display your echo, you should retrieve the inputstream of the connection, and drop all the echoes manually.

Comment: No, flush() doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are overdoing it a bit.  I would recommend a simpler and more efficient method that doesn't have as much overhead, such as using a plain socket.
Client Snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String ip = "Your IP/Hostname";
//set your port
int port = 7391;
Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
s.writeUTF("String To Write To SocketServer");
s.flush();
out.close();
s.close();
}
```

Server Snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(7391);
while (true) {
new SocketWorker(s.accept()).start();
}
}

public static class SocketWorker extends Thread {
Socket s;
public SocketWorker(Socket s) {
this.s = s;
}
@Override
public void run() {
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
//Receive String sent via the client
String response = in.readUTF();
in.close();
s.close();
}
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Edit:  You  will also have to handle Exceptions.  I didn't add any handling obviously.